# Ruby custom sorting of first n elements

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to sort an array of string based on my custom ordering. Problem is I dont know all the elements in array but Im sure that it has 3 strings (high/med/low). So I would like those 3  to be first 3 values . Rest at last

> Eg:
>
> Incoming arrays
>
> array1 = ["high", "not impt" , "med" , "kind of impt" , "low" ]
> array2 = ["low", "rand priority", "med", "high"]

Only high med and low are fixed, rest all keep changing or might not be present at all

> required output
> ["high", "med", "low", rest.(order doesn't matter)]]

I know I can delete and merge, But it will be confusing in code as to why Im doing delete and merge. Any better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [sort_by](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/sort_by) method and implement something like this:

```
["high", "not impt" , "med" , "kind of impt" , "low" ].sort_by do |a|
  ["high", "med", "low"].index(a) || Float::INFINITY
end
```

`index` method returns `0`, `1` and `2` for `"high"`, `"med"` and `"low"` correspondingly and `nil` for other values. Thus, `"high"`, `"med"` and `"low"` is going to be at the beginning and others at the end since every value is less than `Float::INFINITY`

Comment: For some reason its printing same order..Below is the code
https://codepad.remoteinterview.io/JMDYVQGSUV

Comment: That's because `sort_by` doesn't mutate the object it's call on. You should either reassign the result or use `sort_by!` which mutates the object. I updated your code snippet: https://codepad.remoteinterview.io/JMDYVQGSUV